# Fetch Data from Javascript Snippet

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, jquery

**I have the following Javascript snippet that receives an customerID via parameter (i'm going to explain what's going on):**

```
function purchaseEntry(customerid) {
    $('customeridfield').value = customerid;
    if (approvedAgents()) {
        e1 = $('entrylisttable');
        e1.hide();
        getExistingDetails(customerid, 'confirmstatusexistingdetails');
        $('confirmstatushajjlicenceno').value = '';
        $('confirmstatusapproved').checked = false;
        e1 = $('confirmstatus');
        e1.show();
    }

    return false;
}



function getExistingDetails(customerid, existingdetails) {
    e1 = $(existingdetails);
    e1.innerHTML = 'Loading ... <img src="/jpg/ajaxloader.gif" />';

    var url = '/samex/index.php';
    var pars = 'option=com_directory&view=entry2&customerid=' + customerid + '&format=raw';
    new Ajax.Request(url, { method: 'get', parameters: pars,
        onSuccess: function(request) {
            var json = request.responseText.evalJSON();
            jsondata = json['data'];
            e1 = $(existingdetails);
            e1.innerHTML = jsondata['clientdata'];
        },
        onFailure: function(request) {
            e1 = $(existingdetails);
            e1.innerHTML = 'Unable to get information for customer ' + customerid;
        }
        });
}
```

**The HTML looks like:**

`<a href="#" onclick="return purchaseEntry('39384');">`

**Output would look like:**

```
Name: ABC
Address: 123 Street
City: none
Post Code: none
```

**Source code (After saving the single page to my pc):**

```
<div id="confirmstatus" class="optiondiv" style="">
<form id="confirmstatusform">
<table cellspacing="0">
<tbody><tr><td><span class="tableentryhead">Your details in our existing record</span></td>

</tr>
<tr><td><div id="confirmstatusexistingdetails" class="existingdetails">
<table cellspacing="0"><tbody>
<tr>
<td>Name:</td><td>XXXXXXXXXX</td></tr>
<tr><td>Address:</td><td> XXXXXXXXXX </td></tr>
<tr><td>City:</td><td>XXXXXXXXXX</td></tr>
<tr><td>Postcode:</td><td>XXXXXXXXXX</td><
/tr><tr><td>Country:</td><td>XXXXXXXXXX</td></tr>
<tr><td>Telephone:</td><td>XXXXXXXXXX</td></tr>
<tr><td>Fax:</td><td>XXXXXXXXXX</td></tr>
<tr><td>EMail:</td><td>XXXXXXXXXX</td></tr>
<tr><td>Web site:</td><td>XXXXXXXXXX</td></tr>
</tbody></table></div></td></tr>

</tbody></table>
```

***PROBLEM:***

**I need to use PHP to insert the output values XXXXXXXXXX into PHP array through a loop or so.**

***Any suggestion?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for($i++)   
   <tr>
    <td>Name:</td><td><?php 11 ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Address:</td><td> <?php 11 ?> </td></tr>
```

use this in php and echo whole string so.whole u can get at js .Put ajax response in html.

Comment: Ajax is totally new to me. I'm still googling. If you elaborate, i'll appreciate it...